# Is SKReceiptRefreshRequest limited to the testing environment, or can I call it in the final version of the app?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am developing a iOS app that uses In App Purchase, and I am not sure I have a good understanding of `SKReceiptRefreshRequest`. Is it for use only in the testing environment, or can I use it in the final app version on the store? Many features in IAP rely on having an updated receipt, but one problem is that, in the testing environment, firing a `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` causes the app to present a request for Apple ID credentials. If `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` is for use on the final app version too, will it trigger a credentials request also on the user devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling `SKReceiptRefreshRequest` to keep the receipt up to date. As you've seen, any time you access the receipt it could trigger a credentials request. This is because receipts are linked to the iTunes Account on the device.

If you need information from the receipt frequently, what you should be doing is storing it on a server and keeping it up-to-date there. You can use Apple's `/verifyReceipt` endpoint to update the receipt on your server so there's no need to get the user credentials from the device.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your answer. In my application, I am validating the receipt locally. I did not choose server validation because I thought it was only for improved security. But if, as you say, it gives you also the option to keep the receipt always updated in the way you described, then it can be definitely a good Idea. I will mark your answer as correct. Could you please just point me to some documentation in order to achieve this ? thanks

Comment: Hey @AlfonsoTesauro. Receipt validation and subscription status tracking through receipt refreshing are totally different things, but both should be done from a server. There aren't Apple docs on receipt refreshing, it depends a lot on how your backend is configured and what you're trying to track. You'll need background jobs that take receipts and periodically check them with the `/verifyReceipt` endpoint to make sure they're still valid, and update the info in your database. However, there are companies that offer this as a service -> https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs